# How do I programmatically remove/add compound/noncompound percentages and flat amounts from a value?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am given 100 dollars and told that I have to do the following operations on it in order:

Add 97
Add 5
Multiply by a compounded interest of 3%

So essentially, it becomes (100 + 97 + 5) * 1.3 = 208.06

Now here lies my problem, I know to get back to 100 from 208.06, I must do:

208.06 / 1.3 - (97 + 5) = 100

The above is a simple example, but as soon as I start mixing compound,non-compound, flat amounts, and the ability to not only add, but subtract the values, it gets really complicated.  For example, if I am given 100 dollars again and told that I have to apply the following adjustments in order, I am not sure how to reverse it:

1) Add a compound 3%
2) Add a compound 4%
3) Subtract 90
4) Subtract 3
5) Add a non-compound 3%
6) Add a non-compound 4%

The calculation for the above is:

((100 * (1.03) * (1.04)) - 90 - 3) * (1 + 0.04 + 0.03)

For the above, I have no idea how to approach reversing it with just knowing the post adjusted value and the 6 adjustments that were added.

The above formula can be simplified to, which makes it easier to see how to reverse it:

`(100 * 1.03 * (1.04)) - 93 + 7 = 21.21 and to reverse it, we just do:`

`(100 * 1.03 * (1.04)) - 93 + 7 = 100`

My problem is how to loop through it and apply the operations in the correct order.  Do I have to store the order of operations and their amounts in a class and then foreach through each calculation?

I have posted this on Math.StackExchange.com already, but they look at it as one big formula and don't understand that from a programming perspective, I need to loop through each adjustment and take it off the grand total.  This is essentially what I am stuck at, but I am unclear how to approach solving it by looping through each adjustment since it is important that I apply the adjustments in the correct order.  I am not really looking for a solution, but more of a point in the right direction.

Here is an implementation.  Applying it seems to work with the initial sample, but if I do my other one, it does not seem to work unless I am doing something wrong:

```
void Main()
{
var ops = new List<Operation>
{

new CompoundInterest(3.0m),
new CompoundInterest(4.0m),
new Subtract(90.0m),
new Subtract(3.0m),
new NoncompoundInterest(3.0m),
new NoncompoundInterest(4.0m)
};

var applied = ops.Aggregate(100m, (acc, o) => o.Apply(acc));

var unapplied = ops.Reverse().Aggregate(applied, (acc, o) => o.Unapply(acc));

}

// Define other methods and classes here
abstract class Operation
{
public abstract decimal Apply(decimal value);
public abstract decimal Unapply(decimal value);
}
class CompoundInterest : Operation
{
public decimal percent {get;set;}
public CompoundInterest(decimal percent)
{
    this.percent = percent;
}

public override decimal Apply(decimal value)
{
    return value * (1m + percent/100m);
}

public override decimal Unapply(decimal value)
{

    return value / (1m + percent/100m);
}
}
class NoncompoundInterest : Operation { 
public decimal percent {get;set;}
public NoncompoundInterest(decimal percent)
{
    this.percent = percent;
}


public override decimal Apply(decimal value)
{
    return value * (percent/100m);
}

public override decimal Unapply(decimal value)
{
    return value / (percent/100m);
}
}

class Add : Operation { 
public decimal amount {get;set;}
public Add(decimal amount)
{
    this.amount = amount;
}


public override decimal Apply(decimal value)
{
    return value + amount;
}

public override decimal Unapply(decimal value)
{
    return value - amount;
}

}

class Subtract : Operation { 
public decimal amount {get;set;}
public Subtract(decimal amount)
{
    this.amount = amount;
}


public override decimal Apply(decimal value)
{
    return value - amount;
}

public override decimal Unapply(decimal value)
{
    return value + amount;
}
}
```

Comment: I think this is more suited to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dave, I tried there already. The problem is that they look at one big formula, but do not provide any algorithm.  I understand how to apply the formula, but when it comes to coding it, I am having issues on how to approach it.

Comment: PS. From part 1 of your explaination 3% would mean multiply by 1.03...

Comment: @Mark, this could have been a non-compounded 3%, but essentially, when broken out it is the same as 100 * 0.03 = 3 and then 100 + 3 = 103. 100 + (100 * 0.03) = 100 * (1 + 0.03) = 100 * (1.03)

Comment: @Reddog, you are correct, I will edit my post.

Comment: Could you post the link to the formula on Math.StackExchange.com?

Comment: Is each step sequential? You seem to be combining steps when it's not clear if the operations are actually commutative. Is your more complicated formula not more like ((((100 * 1.03) * 1.04) - 90 - 3)/1.03)/1.04 which you can then reliably reverse. You seem to have combined some steps which is making reversing it harder?

Comment: @Andrei, I have posted this before on there, but they are not of help when it comes to programmatically doing it.

Comment: @Dave, I am curious if I am making it more complicated that in really is.  Using your simplified formula, how would you reverse it programmatically?

Comment: @Dave, when it is non-compound, you can't divide 1.03/1.04, you have to divide by 1.03 + 0.04.

Comment: Applying each step should be mutually exclusive and applied sequentially. Define a method for the operation of each step and another for the inverse operation. Iterate through the steps applying each method to reach the result. To undo apply the inverse method to the result for each step in reverse order. Have I understood the problem or am I being stupid and missing something obvious?

Comment: @Dave, I actually feel stupid.  Thanks for the pointers.  I will simplify the formula and add the reverse as well.  If you could make a post with an example using it, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think of this would be as a list of operations, with each operation also providing details how to undo itself. Roughly...

```
abstract class Operation
{
    public abstract decimal Apply(decimal value);
    public abstract decimal Unapply(decimal value);
}

class CompoundInterest : Operation
{
    public CompoundInterest(decimal percent)
    {
        this.percent = percent;
    }

    public override decimal Apply(decimal value)
    {
        return value * (1m + percent/100m);
    }

    public override decimal Unapply(decimal value)
    {
        return value / (1m + percent/100m);
    }
}

class NoncompoundInterest : Operation { ... }

class Add : Operation { ... }

class Subtract : Operation { ... }
```

Now you can represent your chain of operations in a list:

```
var ops = new List<Operation>
{
    new Add(97m),
    new Add(5m),
    new CompoundInterest(3.0m),
};

var applied = ops.Aggregate(100m, (acc, o) => o.Apply(acc));
var unapplied = ops.Reverse().Aggregate(208.06m, (acc, o) => o.Unapply(acc));
```

**Update:** `Aggregate()` works something like like this:

```
decimal acc = 100m;
foreach(Operation o in ops)
    acc = o.Apply(acc);
decimal applied = acc;
```

`(acc, o) => o.Apply(acc)` is a lambda expression representing a function that returns `o.Apply(acc)` given the current "accumulator" (`acc`) and the current item in the sequence (`o`). The "seed" value (100m) is used as the first `acc`, then the function's return value is then passed in as `acc` for the next `o`, and so on.

Comment: Wow thanks for this.  Is this using LINQ, if it is, I don't have access to it because I am using .NET 2.0 :).  I will try to implement this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Google LINQBridge for a 2.0 implementation if you have VS 2008 or 2010. If you don't, you _really_ should upgrade.

Comment: I am running into a slight problem with your code, I think I have it right, but I will update my post.

Comment: I updated my post, I think going forward with my other example does not work either unless I am missing something.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) add `Reverse()` in the `unapplied` calculation, as in my example, and 2) replace `208.06m` with `applied` so you always retrace your steps from the correct amount.

Comment: When I do var unapplied = ops.Reverse().... I get the error message: Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void'

Comment: Also, when I do var applied = ops.Aggregate(100m, (acc, o) => o.Apply(acc)); using the Operations from my larger example: 3 compound, 4 compound, subtract, subtract 3, 3 non-compound, and 4 non-compound, I get 0.01694400 in the applied variable.

Comment: OK, the reverse problem is because List<T> has its own Reverse() method; I was meaning the LINQ version. If you change `var ops` to `IEnumerable<Operation> ops` it will behave.

Are you sure `NoncompoundInterest` is implemented correctly? Multiplying by 0.03 and then 0.04 will indeed produce a small value for `applied`.

Comment: After making the change to IEnumerable<Operation>, the Rervese error went away and I actually got back 100 when passed in applied to unapply, however, like you said, the value for applied seemed to small:  0.01694400

Comment: Can you explain what Aggregate does as far as the syntax? What is acc and o?  What about the scenario where I want to apply a negative 5% compound interest?

Comment: Updated answer with an attempted explanation of `Aggregate()`. I don't know what you mean by "negative 5% compound interest". Unapplying compound interest should be as easy as dividing by the amount you previously multiplied by.